# How to handle a lot of data in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am wanting to build an app that will be handling a lot of data

It will be similar to a dictionary.

The app flow will be that a user searches for a term and the term will be returned back if it exists with some other information.

Since React is just the view, do I need a database to hold the information. It will be a bunch of terms and definitions.

Answer (score 2):

You probably will need a database for your app.
If the data is read-only, you could use a static JSON asset file as your database, but it will probably be very large and less optimized to be filtered/searched than an actual database. 
But if your data structure is not too complex, a JSON file could do the job (and easily be migrated to an actual database in the future if needed).

Answer (score 0):

> do I need a database to hold the information

Yes, you'll need to store dictionary data in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Just for Clarification **React** is a UI Library it does not cater to store huge data information. It depends upon your requirements. You can manage data through **state** . **Redux** is best when application is too complex.

You definitely need a database, i would prefer to go with **NoSQL** it can give you response faster.

Tools that you required

- NodeJS
- MongoDB
- ElasticSearch (Advanced Implementation)